# Calculating the total price in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, oop, components, calculator

So this is my first attempt with React.
I have to calculate the (total)price for a reservation.

The reservation price is determined by a few factors:

- Length of the boat: €1,25 for every meter
- The amount of people: €1 per person
- Use of electricity: €1,25 a day

Let's say the boat is 10m long and 2 people are on there who use electricity. They stay for 2 days. The calculation would be like the following:

- BoatLength(10) * 1.25 * 2 = 25
- AmountOfPeople(2) * 1 * 2 = 4
- UseOfElectricity(true) =  1.25 * 2 = 2.5
- total_price = €25 + €4 + €2.5 = €21.5

I try to implement that in my code, which looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import BoatForm from "./BoatForm";
import StayForm from "./StayForm";

export default class PriceCalculator extends Component {
    /**
     * So, we created a form for the customers so that they can register their boat.
     * Now we want to let them know how much their reservation costs.
     * The size of the boat, amount of people, amount of days and use of electricity are all parameters.
     */

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            boat_length: '',
            amount_of_people: '',
            arrival_date: '',
            leave_date: '',
            use_of_electricity: '',
            box_number: ''
        }
    }

    /**
     * We use date fields in our form to define the stay date of the customer.
     * That means we have to calculate the days ourselves.
     */

    calculateStayTime() {
        const ArrivalDate = new Date(this.state.arrival_date);
        const LeaveDate = new Date(this.state.leave_date);
        // calculate difference
        const DiffTime = Math.abs(LeaveDate - ArrivalDate);
        const DiffDays = Math.ceil(DiffTime / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        let AmountOfDays = DiffDays;
        return AmountOfDays;
    }

    /**
     *  Prices per day:
     *  - Price per meter: 1,25
     *  - Price per person: 1
     *  - Price for using electricity: 1,25
     */

    calculatePrice() {
        const BoatLength = this.state.boat_length;
        const meter_price = 1.25;
        const Persons = this.state.amount_of_people;
        const persons_price = 1;

        let price_per_day = BoatLength * meter_price + Persons * persons_price;


        const electricity_price = 1.25;
        const use_of_electricity = true;
        // ? = if statement
        price_per_day = price_per_day + (use_of_electricity ? electricity_price : 0);
        // const total_price = price_per_day * AmountOfDays;
    }

}
```

I struggle with passing the variables from calculateStayTime() to calculatePrice(). Can anyone help me with how to formulate my calculation to React.JS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the result of `calculateStayTime` inside `calculatePrice`. You can assign the stay time value to a variable but I'd probably just replace the last line: `// const total_price = price_per_day * AmountOfDays;` can be replaced with `const total_price = price_per_day * this.calculateStayTime();` which should give you what you need.

Comment: Thank you! It helped indeed. Now StayTime is linked to the price :)

Comment: @epnic Please accept the answer if it solved your problem :)